# Hide panels from the GUI (project panel and search/replace panel)

Tags: atom-editor

Looking for a way to hide panels in the Atom GUI... First of all the panel that lives on the left by default (project browser?). When editing a single HTML document, I have no need for this.

I also have a bottom panel for search/replace now as a result of hitting ctrl-f. No idea how to get rid of it again.

edit: I found the menu option to toggle the search panel:

```
Find > Toggle find in buffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just disabled "tree-view" package and it has been hidden finally.

[image: preferences]

I hope, it would be helpful for someone else